# Angular material stepper hover

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

How to set css style on step (*Angular material stepper*) when mouse hover it? I tried set styles on `.mat-step-header` and `mat-step`, also i tried set css class on it, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the CSS like below,

```
::ng-deep .mat-step-header:hover{
    background-color: green;
}
```